# Installing Mongodb with Lamp On Ubuntu ( Linux )

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp, lampp

I followed the following steps to install mongo's php drivers with lampp.

http://abstract2paradox.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/adding-mongo-db-driver-to-xampp/

When I start lampp its gives the following error

**Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mongo.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mongo.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0**

Any ideas?

Thanking you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as is outlined by Derick above. Although the way the problem got solved was download a 32 bit version of the ubuntu os and running it as a virtual machine on my pc using vmware. Later followed the 'Manual Installation section' on this [page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.manual) for the php driver installation and it all worked. Got the php drivers from github as mentioned in the page.

Later i copied the file mongo.so from the php file extensions directory running on my virtual machine to my parent os and it all works now!

Answer (score 6):

This means that your PHP is compiled in 32-bit mode, but the mongo extension as 64-bit mode. I believe Apple's compiled PHP is in 32-bit mode as well, you can verify that with:

```
php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX, "\n";'
```

If that shows

```
9223372036854775807
```

you're on a 64-bit platform.

Now, in your case you will need to make sure that you compile the MongoDB extension with a 32-bit architecture. From http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/how-to-build-mongodb-pecl-extension-in-32bit-for-php-52-on-macosx-snow-leaopard I believe you can do that with:

```
pecl download mongo
tar -xvzf mongo-1.2.7.tgz
cd mongo-1.2.7

CFLAGS="-m32"

phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: -thanx, but I am on linux ( Ubuntu ) – Imran Omar Bukhsh

Comment: running php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX, "\n";' gives me 2147483647

Comment: do I need to type 'make install' at the end?

Comment: Uh, yes, you need make install

Comment: well the problem still persists

Comment: There can be a few reasons: You've used the wrong phpize (check whether you have more than one, I think Apple ships PHP (+ phpize) as well, and you need to use the one for lampp. It's also possible that ./configure picked up the wrong php-config binary, again, you need to use the one provided with LAMPP, and you can specify that with <pre>./configure --with-php-config=PATH</pre>

Comment: indeed it was using the wrong php and specifying the path sovled the php bit of the problem....it still give the same error though...whilst compiling it says : checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Comment: 'which phpsize' says : /opt/lampp/bin/phpize

Comment: command i used for configure : sudo ./configure  --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config

Comment: find out alternative solution below, thanx for the help

Comment: php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX, "\n";'

give me  9223372036854775807

but still facing same above problem
please help me